# Custom Tmap palette based on results

Tags: r, shiny, visualization, r-sf, tmap

I'm trying to create a custom palette for tmap in R where the colours represent a result from a general election.

In the below photo you can see my plot doesn't have a palette attached and is using the default colours, is it possible to assign colours to each of the possible results, eg SNP = yellow, Liberal Democrat = Orange, Labour = red and Conservative = blue?

[image]

My code for the plot currently is:

```
output$map <- renderTmap({
    tm_shape(filterConst()) +
      tm_polygons(
        "first_party",
        title = "Results",
        popup.vars = c("Winner:" = "first_party", "MP" = "mp"),
        zindex = 401
      ) +
      tm_layout(frame = FALSE) +
      tmap_mode("view")
  })
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Have tried using a custom palette, but when filtering at constituency level, the palette does not represent the parties colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a palette - a named vector linking the names of parties to colors. For more info consider consulting the tmap Book https://r-tmap.github.io/tmap-book/visual-variables.html#colors

Since you did not share your data, and it was not practical for me to look some UK data up myself, I am demonstrating the technique on the good ol' North Carolina shapefile that ships with the `{sf}` package.

As a bonus I had fun with choosing the "proper" county names...

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)


shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # included with sf package

shape <- shape %>% 
  mutate(winner = case_when(NAME == "Halifax" ~ "Conservative",
                            NAME == "Wilson" ~ "Labor",
                            NAME == "Scotland" ~ "SNP",
                            NAME == "Pitt" ~ "Libdem",
                            T ~ NA)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(winner))



tm_shape(shape) +
  tm_polygons(col = "winner",
              title = "Results",
              # here is the action!!! 
              palette = c("Conservative" = "blue", 
                          "Labor" = "red",
                          "SNP" = "yellow",
                          "Libdem" = "orange"))
```

[image: four counties in North Carolina, color coded]

Comment: Thank you! Don't know how i didn't manage to find this document, this and your answer are very helpful!

Comment: Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom color palette:

```
library(tmap)
library(dplyr)

tmap_mode("view")
data("World")

states <- World %>% 
  filter(name %in% c("Austria", "Germany", "Poland", "Hungary", "Czech Rep.", "Slovakia")) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("Austria", "Germany", "Poland", "Hungary", "Czech Rep.", "Slovakia")))

# create custom color palette
custpal = c("darkred", "orange", "palegreen", "dodgerblue", "purple3", "gold")

tm_shape(states) +
    tm_polygons("name", palette = custpal)
```

[image]